# Caching google fonts using workbox

Tags: workbox

Can someone help and tell me how to cache google fonts using workbox-build. I want to include the url in the files to precache but that have been impossible for me. Unlike the normal service worker where all I have to do is include the url in the list of files to cache during the install event. please I have stuck on this all day.

Answer (score 2):

You can cache google fonts within your webpack config using `workbox-webpack-plugins`:

```
import { GenerateSW } from 'workbox-webpack-plugins';
```

and then drop the following fn into your plugins:

```
    new GenerateSW({
      runtimeCaching: [
        {
          urlPattern: /^https:\/\/fonts\.gstatic\.com/,
          handler: 'StaleWhileRevalidate',
          options: {
            cacheName: 'google-fonts-webfonts'
          }
        }
      ]
    }),
```

This is a slightly modified version of the Google common recipe linked in a different answer. The code above will look the same as the workbox fn at runtime.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/common-recipes

Answer (score 1):

I managed to cache google fonts using:

```js
       workbox.routing.registerRoute(
            /^https:\/\/fonts\.googleapis\.com/,
            new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
                cacheName: 'google-fonts-stylesheets',
            })
        );
```

from: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/common-recipes

Answer (score 0):

Precaching Google Fonts is not possible, due to the varying nature of the underlying URLs, and the fact that you won't know what the specific versioned URL for the font file is until the CSS definition is downloaded.

The current recommended best practices for using Workbox along with Google Fonts can be found in the Workbox [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/common-recipes#google_fonts).

As an alternative, if you do want to precache fonts, I'd recommend finding a font family that's available under a permissive license, and [host a copy of it on your own web server](https://developers.google.com/fonts/faq#can_i_download_the_fonts_on_google_fonts_to_my_own_computer). Keeping it local along with your other assets should make it straightforward to precache using Workbox.

Answer (score 0):

Exact copy of the Common Recipe for webpack based on the great answer by kylie

```
    new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
      //clientsClaim: true,
      //skipWaiting: true,
      runtimeCaching: [
        {
          urlPattern: /^https:\/\/fonts\.googleapis\.com/,
          handler: "StaleWhileRevalidate",
          options: {
            cacheName: "google-fonts-stylesheets"
          }
        },
        {
          urlPattern: /^https:\/\/fonts\.gstatic\.com/,
          handler: "CacheFirst",
          options: {
            cacheName: "google-fonts-webfonts",
            cacheableResponse: {
              statuses: [0, 200]
            },
            expiration: {
              maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365,
              maxEntries: 30
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    })
```